# PHP send 200 status and close connection without sending any content in Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to work with Paypal's IPN and they state that I should 'return an empty HTTP 200 response'. I need to return this and then for the PHP script to continue processing.

There are loads of examples on stack overflow and other places that show how to use the 'connection: close' header with output buffering to send a response to the client and keep processing. However, no solution I've found works when the content length is set to zero. Whenever I set a content length header of zero, the connection remains open until the script terminates.

How can I terminate a connection early, send no content and continue processing?

**UPDATE:**

**ob_flush()** won't help here. It will flush the buffer, but it wont close the connection. If you set the headers connection: close and a non zero content-length header then the connection will be closed from the client side when you have sent content-length bytes; this is where ob_flush() can help. However if you set a content length of zero and flush a buffer without anything in it, then nothing gets sent to the client and the connection remains open.

Comment: What do you mean by "continue processing"? You want to return code 200 and then do somethhing else during the same request? Could you link the PayPal docs that tell you to do this? I think you might have misunderstood how that should work

Comment: It turns out I've made an incorrect assumption. I was referring to this document https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/ in the section IPN Protocol and Architecture, under point 2 of the protocol steps. I'd incorrectly assumed that you had send back the empty 200 response, before you continued with the verification, but it turns out that is not the case and the 200 status can wait right until the end. Whilst I've fixed the problem I was having, the question still stands in the abstract, how to send an empty response and let the scrip continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a fork mechanism : send 200 il parent while processing data in the child.
You can also use ReactPHP for asynchronous processing or some queuing systems like JmsJobQueue : the processing is done in a separate script that you call and pass arguments to.